# Javascript - Check if alert is present and dismiss it

Tags: javascript, alert

I am trying to do some validations in the SNOW application where the developers did something like:
When I click on a button, an alert box will be displayed.

To test this, I am trying to click the button first, and need to check if the alert is present. If possible, need to check the message and dismiss the alert.

I am using plain JavaScript, and trying to get hold of this alert component but couldn't get a solution. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Note: There is no Selenium or any similar APIs involved here, just plain javascript as only that's allowed for my coding area.

I have tried like:

```
document.getElementById('abc').click();
window.alert() == null // just to check if alert exists
```

I understand, window.alert will produce an alert dialog, but not sure how to get hold of it. I want to get the already existing alert and dismiss it.

Comment: While an alert is displaying the rest of JavaScript is blocked. So you can't detect it, because your code won't run until the user dismisses the alert.

Comment: Is it a traditional alert() that pops up or is it a modal that is made to be used as an alert? If it is a normal alert, one option is to use javascript to REMOVE the event handler from that button and replace it with your own. Then you can use your own validation functionality. This allows you to stop the alert from happening in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You can not control the alert and interact with it in JavaScript. You can override the method and call other code with it.

Basic idea below:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

const _alert = window.alert;
window.alert = (txt) => {
  console.log(`alert called with '${txt}'`);
};

btn.click();

window.alert = _alert;
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="alert(this.id);">Click</button>
```